# how to configure spring-5 “webclient (with jetty connector)” webflux with mediatype "application/x-ndjson"

Tags: java, spring, webclient, mime-types, spring-webflux

I am trying to access rest end point which will return response with mediatype "application/x-ndjson" header. How to consume this endpoint with spring 5 Webclient? 
Will it work if I set media type to "application/stream+json" in Spring 5 WebClient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create your own `Jackson2JsonDecoder` with all the media types you'd like to support (including this specific mediatype).

Something like:

```java
Jackson2JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = new Jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build(), 
    new MimeType("application", "json"), new MimeType("application", "x-ndjson"));
```

And then configure this decoder directly in the WebClient while building it:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(jsonDecoder)).build();
```

If you're using Spring Boot, you can achieve all that with:

```java
@Configuration
public class JsonConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CodecCustomizer ndJsonCustomizer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    Jackson2JsonDecoder jsonDecoder = new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, 
        new MimeType("application", "json"), new MimeType("application", "x-ndjson"));
    return codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(jsonDecoder);
  }

}
```

In the future, you might not need to do that since the Spring Framework team is [considering ndjson support out-of-the-box to replace stream+json](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21283).